# SharePoint online SearchBox web part not available

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have several customers on Office365/SharePoint Online. I have an administration account in all those subscriptions that's actually the Global Admin.

The thing is that in some clients, the main Team Site allows me to add a **SearchBox** web part to the home page. In others, that web part is simply not available to be added.

When I check the web part catalog  (`<site_url>/_catalogs/wp`) I'm able to "edit" each web part on those sites where the web part is available for addition. In the sites where I can't add the web part, I can't edit it either.

**Note:** by site I'm refrering to another Team Site in a different Office365/Sharepoint online subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: I had to enable Custom scripting for SharePoint Online... something that Microsoft has set now to Disabled by default. The I had to wait about 24 hrs and the web parts were accessible.